# Filter meta request

Tags: multisite, meta-query

i've got a multisite where i query *specific custom post types* from *one specific blog*. It looks like this:

```
function unify_results_filter( $input ) {
global $wpdb;
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
$blog_source_id = '2';

$db_source_prefix = str_replace($blog_id, $blog_source_id, $wpdb->prefix);

// if blog is not 2 and post_type is results, query blog id 2
if ( strpos($input, "post_type = 'results'") !== false )
    $input = str_replace( $wpdb->posts, $db_source_prefix . 'posts', $input );

return $input;
}
add_filter( 'posts_request', 'unify_results_filter' );
```

Now this works for the posts themselves. However, i'd like to the *same for their meta values*. Is there a similar filter for meta request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use wp_query to retrieve posts. Its's easy to include meta values in wp_query and a safe way to retrieve posts from wordpress database.

use this code to switch to the desired blog id and then after retrieving posts switch back to the original blog.

```
<?php
    /* 
       for global variables, since it is being changed or updated from time to time,
       please refer to Related Resources for more information
    */
    global $switched;
    switch_to_blog(2);
    echo 'You switched from blog ' . $switched . ' to 2';
      **//RUN WP_QUERY HERE**
    restore_current_blog();
    echo 'You switched back.';
?>
```

References:

[Wp_query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

[Switch to Blog Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog)

Comment: Thank you for your input, you saved my day. Sometimes i just choose bad solutions and get cycled :/

Comment: Not just you. It happens with all of us :)